# AngularJS access to Cbssports REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors

I am trying to create an angularjs application as a cbssports plugin.

They provide a RESTful API.

The following is my $http request:

```
$http.get(basePath + 'league/owners?access_token=' + cbssportsTokens['access_token'] + '&response_format=JSON')
        .success(function(data) {
           return data;
        });
```

That is wrapped up in a factory and used in a controller. As far as I can tell this is getting executed correctly. When I look at the chrome developer tools I can see the following error on my request from the console:

```
OPTIONS http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/league/owners?access_token=U2FsdGVkX18Hyd0…J9DrpO7C-OXQQNXGMh0ej0iXVfPf5DkQwkLwSpCqGhipd6HogV_gZ&response_format=JSON angular.js:8560
(anonymous function) angular.js:8560
sendReq angular.js:8354
$http.serverRequest angular.js:8087
wrappedCallback angular.js:11572
wrappedCallback angular.js:11572
(anonymous function) angular.js:11658
Scope.$eval angular.js:12701
Scope.$digest angular.js:12513
Scope.$apply angular.js:12805
done angular.js:8378
completeRequest angular.js:8592
xhr.onreadystatechange
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.cbssports.com/fantasy/league/owners?access_token=U2FsdGVkX18xBod…oQWvjDVSbpZCOVsoIKeVXKRSYdo6dBbIE0rgMWTkWhmgPUTyr_xnS&response_format=JSON. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.cbssports.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9001' is therefore not allowed access. ?access_token=U2FsdGVkX18xBodWEOfeqys5X4aDpghYrE22FGljlJd_TtKRHlWh4LHWFwVxay95BbAWvn4te1foQWvjDVSbp…:1
```

When I click the link that it said it couldn't load, it takes me to a new page with the expected output!! So clearly CORS shouldn't be an issue here from the server.

I have read many different issues with CORS about changing the headers. The follow is how I have set it up:

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin';
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, also my first post to SO, so please let me know if more info would help.

Comment: All I'm using is `$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;` and `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];` To use CORS. Although, I am using $resource.

Comment: I've also tried that, it results in the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't exactly get it to work. But I found a sort of workaround.

```
 function _get(url) {
     return $resource(basePath + url, {
           access_token: cbssportsTokens['access_token'],
           response_format: 'JSON',
           callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
     }, {
        get: {
           method: 'JSONP'
        }
     });
  }
```

I went ahead and used a JSONP request instead of a GET, the cbs server seems to be happier with that.